# How to use web scraping to log off from my website?

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I need help to logout from my web page once all of my reporting work is done. I have code to login and work with the web page, but I'm facing problem to logout of my web page. Below is the code that I use:

```
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim ieDoc As Object
Dim ieTable As Object
Dim clip As DataObject
Set ie = New InternetExplorer
With ie
    .Visible = True
    .navigate "abc.com"
     Do Until .readyState = 4
     DoEvents
     Loop
     ("UserName").Value = "****"
     ("Password").Value = "*******"
     .submit
End With
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'my body of the code goes here
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''' 
'''''Before the Sub ends i need the logout code to logout from the web page

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clicking the logout anchor tag (target by id)

```
ie.document.querySelector("#LogoutLink").click
```